# Are any of the Forge APIs able to tell me the version of the software that created that created file

Tags: autodesk-forge

If I upload a Revit file can any API tell me what version it was created with? Same for dwg, 3ds and any other file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forge [Design Automation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/) APIs might help this case, you can use cloud engines of Autodesk product (such as AutoCAD, Revit, Inventor, etc.) to read file details. What you have to do is writing some tiny add-ins to read software version stored in the file.

Besides, you can use some third-party tools to archive the same goal as well:

1. RVT file is actually an OLE document, you can use `OLE library for .NET` to read software version inside RVT, please check this blog [Basic File Info and RVT File Version](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html) from Jeremy.
2. The DWG can be read as a text file, you can use the regular expression to extract the version number out, please refer [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-find-which-version-of-AutoCAD-was-used-to-create-save-a-DWG.html).