# Get Revit Version of BIM 360 File using Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to find the Revit version of a file on BIM 360 without downloading the .rvt file? I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141340/are-any-of-the-forge-apis-able-to-tell-me-the-version-of-the-software-that-creat), and Eason's answer suggests using the Design Automation APIs; however, currently the Design Automation API only supports AutoCAD. I know there's a Design Automation for Revit in beta, but is there any way of getting the Revit version without DA4R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates 2022-09-08:

Sorry for the late update. We can now get the Revit version from the response of [Model Derivative Manifest API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET). If you don't see that, please reupload your model to BIM360 to trigger translation.

```json
"name": "rac_basic_sample_project.rvt",
"progress": "complete",
"outputType": "svf2",
"properties": {
    "Document Information": {
        "RVTVersion": "2022",
        "Project Name": "Sample House",
        "Project Number": "001-00",
        "Author": "Samuel Macalister",
        "Project Address": "Enter address here",
        "Project Issue Date": "Issue Date",
        "Project Status": "Project Status",
        "Building Name": "Samuel Macalister sample house design",
        "Client Name": "Autodesk",
        "Organization Name": "Autodesk",
        "Organization Description": ""
    }
},
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70664111/7745569 to know how to get the derivative urn from the model version tip.

===========

Unfortunately, it's not possible currently. Both Forge Data Management API and Forge Model Derivative API won't care about the file metadata inside the RVT files as I know. The possible way is via Design Automation API for Revit, if you don't want to download RVT to your machines to check its metadata.

Comment: I wonder has there been any improvement to the Forge API on this front? It seems rather hacky to have to download (a portion) of a Revit file just to see what version it is saved in when Forge/BIM360 is all about object metadata.

Comment: Now that it has been a couple of years I wonder if there has been any updates on this question. I have my Design Automation AppBundle in several Revit versions and would like to open the correct version to prevent an upgrade or error. Is there any way to find the Revit version of a BIM 360 project or file, before sending my workitem?