# Reliably Determine Revit Version of BIM 360 Project

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-designautomation

Design Automation AppBundles for Revit require the identification of the Revit engine, which includes the version (year) of Revit. So to make a Design Automation to support multiple Revit versions, there will be multiple AppBundles, and multiple Activities based on these years. Which is no problem, but how do I determine the version year of the BIM 360 project or the .rvt file to submit a work item to the correct activity? It seems like this data should be available since Revit will only list BIM360 Projects that are in the same version as the copy of Revit opened.

[This thread from 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594921/get-revit-version-of-bim-360-file-using-forge) suggests it is not possible, but has that changed?

I also found [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/check-version-revit-file-hosted-cloud) to download the beginning of the file to get this data, but this appears to only work on single user files, and does not work for workshared RVT files, and all of our BIM360 projects are workshared.

Are there any new options?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm in search of a method to determine the Revit version of a workshared RVT file that is stored in BIM 360. Preferably without downloading the file from BIM 360. The Revit version of the entire "Project" on BIM 360 would work as well, but I don't see that in the project information returned by the BIM 360 API or the Data Management API.

Comment: Also discussed in the answer to [Is it possible to obtain the version of the RVT file that is uploaded to BIM360 Document management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086842/is-it-possible-to-obtain-the-version-of-the-rvt-file-that-is-uploaded-to-bim360)

Answer (score 2):

Update: In his [tweet](https://twitter.com/augustomaia/status/1488659966508494848?s=20&t=7ZuBlPUEqTi8tIiItmXnOQ), [Augusto](https://twitter.com/augustomaia) points out that you can now [check the version of a Revit file hosted on the cloud](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/check-version-revit-file-hosted-cloud) simply by reading the `RVTVersion` attribute in the `Document Information` manifest properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the Revit version of an RVT file by accessing its [BasicFileInfo properties](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/475edc09-cee7-6ff1-a0fa-4e427a56262a.htm). This can be done without opening the file in question. However, it does require the Revit API, and hence a Revit installation.

The Building Coder shares some other solution enabling Revit RVT file version determination without the Revit API, cf., e.g., [RvtVerFileOpen – Open Correct RVT File Version](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/05/automatically-open-correct-rvt-file-version.html#4) and [Determining RVT File Version Using Python](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/06/determining-rvt-file-version-using-python.html).

Comment: In my case the RVT files are stored on BIM 360 projects in the cloud. By the time the Revit API is open on the Design Automation sandbox, it is already too late, the work item has been submitted and the file downloaded and possibly upgraded. I would like to determine the version of the Revit file before posting the work item, and without needing to download it off of BIM 360 to a 3rd location.

Comment: I assume you would need to download the RVT file from BIM360 in order to use your local tools to perform the version analysis before submitting the appropriate Design Automation job. Alternatively, implement a lookup table mapping RVT to version number and populate it before uploading the model to BIM360, or before updating. You could automate this in a Revit API desktop add-in, in the `OnSaving` event.