# Is it possible to obtain the version of the RVT file that is uploaded to BIM360 Document management?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-webhooks

I am using Forge's Webhook API to manage the files that are uploaded to our BIM360 Projects. Is there a way to look up the version of the RVT file (for example, if is a Revit 2022 file or a 2018)?

Comment: Also check the answer on how to [Reliably Determine Revit Version of BIM 360 Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135095/reliably-determine-revit-version-of-bim-360-project).

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you have downloaded the `RVT` project file, you can determine the Revit file version last used to save it using the various following methods in chronological order:

- [RVT File Version](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2008/10/rvt-file-version.html)
- [RFA Version and Context, Grey Commands, RDB Link](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/06/rfa-version-grey-commands-family-context-and-rdb-link.html)
- [Basic File Info and RVT File Version](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html)
- [Upgrading Family Files Silently, Part 2](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/07/upgrading-family-files-silently-part-2.html)
- [Determining RVT File Version Using Python](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/06/determining-rvt-file-version-using-python.html)
- [Automatically Open Correct RVT File Version](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/05/automatically-open-correct-rvt-file-version.html)
- [Determining RVT File Version for DA4R Workitem](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/11/document-session-id-api-context-and-external-events.html#4)

Comment: Sorry, but I think I wasn't clear on the question. I was looking for a way to get the version of the RVT file without having to download the file again (as it is not feasible due to the size of the files).
For example, is there an endpoint of any Forge API to obtain that information from the RVT file once it is already uploaded in BIM360?

Comment: ... checking with the devteam for you...

Comment: A set of new endpoints that include this functionality is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Revit version used to save the file by downloading just a few bytes of it, not the whole `RVT` file: [Check the version of a Revit file hosted on the cloud](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/check-version-revit-file-hosted-cloud).

Answer (score 0):

The development ticket `RVTLMV-2277` is now in production.

You can view the version inside the manifest; I just did a quick test:

```
"Document Information": {
     "RVTVersion": "2017",
```

Addendum:

Some additional notes on the blog post:

- The information is not always in the first 10kb of the file; it could be anywhere. You can dissect the file format and find it though through repeated downloading of different bytes from the file. The amount downloaded and therefore time to calculate the Revit version can vary a lot.
- The encoding for the text information isn’t always UTF-16 BE (Big Endian). The bits in the file may line up so that you must use UTF-16 LE.
- Sometimes the file offered by the Forge API is not the direct `.rvt` file but a zip file with the `.rvt` file in it. In these cases, you will need to dissect the zip format to get to the correct `.rvt` file underneath.

Comment: Excuse me, when you say "inside the manifest" do you mean the response you get with the call to the GET manifest endpoint of the Model Derivative API?

Because if that is the case, the version did not appear there. :(

Comment: I'm checking with Augusto, who provided and verified this info.

Comment: it should work for models translated after Nov 4th, 2021, are you able to provide a URN where it's not visible?

Comment: That's there, I see `"RVTVersion": "2022"`

Comment: We will follow up this with you via email at forge.help@autodesk.com.
I really appreciate your support. Greetings!