# how to check if bucket object is already translated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I've uploaded file to oss and have object id, if bucket object is not yet translated then how to check derivatives info. with object id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward, just base64 encode your objectId, then call [GET {urn}/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/). If it returns a 404 http status code, then it means this URN hasn't got translated.

If your file is stored on BIM360/ACC, you will need to get derivative URN from the file's version tip. Please follow this tutorial, but find `relationships.data.derivatives.data.id` instead for the URN like the below for example.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/download-document/#step-4-find-the-storage-object-id-for-the-file

```
"derivatives": {
    "data": {
        "type": "derivatives",
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLkVueWtrU3FjU0lPVTVYMGhRdy1mQUM_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
    },
    // ...
},
```

Node.js code sample tested with [yiskang/forge-viewmodels-nodejs-svf2](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewmodels-nodejs-svf2)

```js
const {
    DerivativesApi
} = require('forge-apis');

const { getClient, getPublicToken } = require('./routes/common/oauth');

const derivativeApi = new DerivativesApi();

const urn = 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXlidWNrZXQvdGVzdC5ydnQ';

getPublicToken().then(accessToken => {
    derivativeApi.getManifest(urn, {}, null, accessToken).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.statusCode, res.statusMessage);
    },
    function (err) {
        // When the urn hasn't got translated, it goes here
        console.error('error', err.statusCode, err.statusMessage);
        // if you want to redire page to some where, write your codes here
    });
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70664111/7745569

Comment: right, didn't explore derivatives in depth yet, thanks Eason and have a great weekend

Comment: i tested in JS, seems not working, see below code FYI,
var urn = item.objectId.toBase64();
var status = null;
var derivatives = new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi()
  .getManifest(urn, {}, null, tokenInternal)
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .then((d) => {
    return d.statusCode;
  });
const checkStatus = async () => {
  status = await derivatives;
  console.log(status);
};
checkStatus();
if (status === 404) return;

Comment: well, it's promise and/or async related issue, above code is inside a promise, since getManifest is also a promise, need to get the result before continuing i.e. @ last line of code "if (status === 404) return;", how to achieve it? in short, inside promise A -> first get result of promise B ->then use that result to continue in promise A

Comment: hi Eason, maybe it's not promise and/or async related issue, 404 error will be generated by server and sent to client, right? so how to use it directly in server, what i want to achieve is to check if already uploaded bucket object is translated, if not then do translation.

Comment: you cannot simply redirect to another route after catch 404 error, right?

Comment: It sounds like a node.js routing issue, rather than Forge... I added my test case above. You will need to write your redirect logic in where I put comments.

Comment: thanks Eason, I did try your method (added redirect @ 404), not working well, I guess part of reason is that code segment is nested inside forEach loop which is also nested in another promise, in fact, I'm referring to GitHub sample of "forge-view.googledrive.models" and try to add checking Derivatives so alreadyTranslated is really the case.