# Get Revit Version of a model in BIM 360/ACC via Document management/Model derivative

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I'm attempting to develop an application to aid in managing my company's model. One aspect of this project involves analyzing all C4R (Collaboration for Revit) models within the BIM360 and ACC (Autodesk Construction Cloud) platforms. I came across a thread on Stack Overflow that seemed relevant, but I've been struggling to follow it successfully.

The Stack Overflow thread in question can be found here:
[Is there a way to get the Revit Version from either the Project or Item in the Forge APIs without downloading the .rvt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558400/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-revit-version-from-either-the-project-or-item-in-the-f)

I'm curious about where I can locate the "manifest" method that's mentioned in the thread. I did manage to find it in the documentation, but it appears to have a different response structure. You can find information about the "manifest" method here: Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API Manifest Method.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/

I'm also uncertain about what the "urn" of a file is. Is it equivalent to the file's ID, and should I perform any conversions before using it? Here's an image for reference: Image Description.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0diU.png)

Lastly, I'm wondering whether I should consider using the "Metadata" method instead of the "manifest" method for my application.

Thanks in advance

i tried to go over decomantation and the attached thread from stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version of Revit that most models were created by using the model derivative API. Kindly have a look at the response in the  derivatives>properties>Document Information.

The link to the documentation is below
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/